# Mysql Docker container issue

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

while trying to setup mysql with docker the container keeps crashing, giving the below exception

```
2020-08-27 07:24:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.31-1debian10 started.
2020-08-27 07:24:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-08-27 07:24:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.31-1debian10 started.
2020-08-27 07:24:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2020-08-27T07:24:42.834012Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-08-27T07:24:42.835348Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2020-08-27T07:24:42.835404Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

the given directory was empty and also tried with a different new volume

below is the docker compose

```
services:
  911-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: 911-db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
      - MYSQL_TCP_PORT=3365
    ports: 
      - '3365:3365'
    expose: 
      - '3365'
    volumes:
      - /Users/uesrname/workspace/mysql/5.7:/var/lib/mysql/data
```

Comment: try to change `.../5.7:/var/lib/mysql/data` with `.../5.7:/var/lib/mysql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the mysql image usage the data volume should map to "/var/lib/mysql".

Try changing this: "/Users/uesrname/workspace/mysql/5.7:/var/lib/mysql/data"

to this: "/Users/uesrname/workspace/mysql/5.7:/var/lib/mysql"